# '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: angular, typescript, strict-mode

I'm facing this error in my code when using strict mode and I'm not managing it.

```
"message": "Type 'MyType<string>[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method
```

It is happenning in this line of code:

```
const [optionAll, ...options] = await service.getLineOfBusiness().toPromise();
```

this service method returns an observable of a list of MyType:

```
public getLineOfBusiness(): Observable<MyType<string>[]>
```

This MyType is quite simple interface:

```
export interface MyType<T = unknown> {
   key: string;
   value: T;
   extra?: string;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyType<string>[]` can be destructured with array-like syntax but `undefined` cannot.

If you are sure that `getLineOfBusiness()` will always return an array in this specific usage (and not `undefined`), you could add a non-null assertion (`!`) to the awaited expression to suppress the error:

```
const [optionAll, ...options] = (await service.getLineOfBusiness().toPromise())!;
```